# how can I change url style in rails 4 app with mongoid

Tags: mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Mongoid.

now my rails app url like this `http://localhost:3000/posts/523605c9d9d834ee00000002`

How can I change the url style like `http://localhost:3000/posts/1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is not use the default BSON::ObjectId for id on your posts collection.
I had a similar use case that needed a numeric id for my collection, and I created this gem which makes easier to have this functionality.

You can check it out, in here.
https://github.com/arthurnn/mongoid_integer_id

Comment: What do you mean even numbers? it should be a sequencial series.